# Configuring keycloak saml from the command line

Tags: saml, keycloak

I have successfully set up keycloak and am able to manually set up SAML authentication for my service provider through the web console.

However I need to automate this and so far I have hit two things I can't do through the command line (using kcadm.sh):

1. My metadata is in XML, not JSON format.   The create client call seems to requires JSON.  The GUI handles XML fine.  Do you know a way around this?
2. I need to disable 'client signature required' which defaults to enabled.  I can't work out how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use Administration REST API directly from CLI.

Comment: I know I can use it, I just don't know the syntax.  I am already using it for creating realms, users, etc.  but I am stuck on the two points above.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. Using the Network trace tool in Chrome, I found out that Keycloak actually uses an (undocumented) converter that first converts the XML to JSON... So here's how I solved this issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
KEYCLOAK_URL="http://mykeycloakserver.mydomain:8080"
TOKEN_URL="${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
#AUTH="Authorization: bearer $(curl -d client_id=admin-cli -d username=admin -d password=admin -d grant_type=password ${TOKEN_URL} | sed -n 's|.*"access_token":"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p')"
AUTH="Authorization: bearer $(curl -d client_id=admin-cli -d username=admin -d password=admin -d grant_type=password ${TOKEN_URL} | jq -r '.access_token')"

CONVERTER_URL="${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/admin/realms/mykeycloakrealm/client-description-converter"
SAML_XML="@/tmp/saml_export/iam_saml.xml"
CLIENT_JSON=$(curl -X POST -H "${AUTH}"  -H 'content-type: application/json' ${CONVERTER_URL} --data-binary ${SAML_XML=})

CLIENTS_URL="${KEYCLOAK_URL}/auth/admin/realms/mykeycloakrealm/clients"
curl -X POST -H "${AUTH}"  -H 'content-type: application/json' ${CLIENTS_URL} -d ${CLIENT_JSON}
```

So, first call the converter to convert your XML, then use the JSON result to create a client.

(By the way,: my code sample contains a commented alternative in case you don't have 'jq')

Answer (score 0):

Using Keycloak 21.0.1 and BASH shell (with curl and jq):

```
TOKEN_URL="${KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"

AUTH="Authorization: bearer $(curl -s -d client_id=admin-cli -d username=${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN} -d password=${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD} -d grant_type=password ${TOKEN_URL} | jq -r '.access_token')"

CONVERTER_URL="${KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}/admin/realms/${KEYCLOAK_REALM}/identity-provider/import-config"
       
JSON=$(curl -s -X POST -H "${AUTH}"  -H 'content-type: application/json' ${CONVERTER_URL} -d '{"fromUrl":"'${KEYCLOAK_IMPORT_FROM}'","providerId":"saml"}')
                                
${KEYCLOAK_HOME}/bin/kcadm.sh create identity-provider/instances -r ${KEYCLOAK_REALM} -s alias=${KEYCLOAK_ALIAS} \
-s providerId=saml \
-s enabled=true \
-s displayName="${KEYCLOAK_DISPLAY_NAME}" \
-s config=${JSON}
```

Using environment variables:

| *NAME* | *DESCRIPTION* | *EXAMPLE* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL | URL to Keycloak admin | `https://keycloak.example.com/auth` |
| KEYCLOAK_ADMIN | Admin username | admin |
| KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD | Admin password | password |
| KEYCLOAK_REALM | Realm name | test |
| KEYCLOAK_IMPORT_FROM | URL of SAML XML descriptor metadata | `https://idp.example.com/shibboleth` |
| KEYCLOAK_HOME | Path to Keycloak install | /opt/keycloak |
| KEYCLOAK_ALIAS | Keycloak IdP alias field | saml |
| KEYCLOAK_DISPLAY_NAME | Friendly name of new SAML IdP | SAML |